# Get Gravity Forms Input Value, store as variable in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gravityforms

I have a WooCommerce site with Gravity forms and a plugin called WooCommerce Gravity Forms Product Add-ons that allows me to add a Gravity Forms form to a product.

I would like to hide a woocommerce payment gateway based on the selection of one of the radio inputs in the Gravity Form that is on the product.

I know that the form is ID 1 and I know the field I'm interested in (a radio input) is field 8.

I have tried a number of things based on Gravity Forms documentation as well as documentation from the payment gateway and from StackOverflow posts.

```
// remove Partial.ly for hospice selection

add_action('gform_after_submission_1', 'get_hospice_info', 10, 2); 
function get_hospice_info($entry, $form) {
$hospiceinfo = $entry['8'];
}

function hospice_selector_remove_partially($gateway) {
if ($hospiceinfo = "Yes, member under hospice or hospital care") {
$unset = true;
}
if ( $unset == true ) unset( $gateway['partially'] );
return $gateway;
}     add_action('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','hospice_selector_remove_partially');
```

I feel i'm close. But it is removing the gateway even when the other radio option is selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated if possible.

Comment: Can you show us screenshots?

Comment: Of the Gravity form fields or of the payment step of checkout (or both)?

Comment: The screen shot of the form field: https://nimb.ws/ShKRBk
The screen shot of the checkout: https://nimb.ws/DwXpPT

You'll see that "No, member not under hospice/hospital care" is selected. Which means the payment plan should show up IF i actually had the function written correctly.

Please let me know if you were looking for different screen shots.

Comment: I am looking for a very similar solution. Actually the same! Did you sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Janna--

The `get_hospice_info` function sets a variable, `$hospiceinfo`, which is only in the [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of that particular function. Therefore, `$hospiceinfo` will be undefined in the `hospice_selector_remove_partially` function. You would have to set `$hospiceinfo` as a global variable.

Secondly, even if the variable was available in the `hospice_selector_remove_partially` function, the single `=` in the first line of said function actually sets the variable equal to the value "Yes, member under hospice or hospital care". You would need at least two `==` to compare the value. This is an often overlooked typo, which is why WP states [yoda conditions](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/#yoda-conditions) are a best practice.

Please see the following code which addresses the above listed concerns, as well as removes unnecessary code:

```
add_action('gform_after_submission_1', 'get_hospice_info', 10, 2); 
function get_hospice_info($entry, $form) {
    global $hospiceinfo;
    $hospiceinfo = $entry['8'];
}

function hospice_selector_remove_partially($gateway) {
    global $hospiceinfo;
    if ("Yes, member under hospice or hospital care" == $hospiceinfo ) {
        unset( $gateway['partially'] );
    }
    return $gateway;
}   
add_action('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','hospice_selector_remove_partially');
```

Now, this answer assumes that both of these actions are called during the same page load and that the `gform_after_submission` action is called prior to the `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` action. This would have to be verified to be sure the above code will actually provide the desired outcome.

Ideally, you would fetch the value of the `hospice_info` field during the `woocommerce_available_payment_gateways` action and do away with the `gform_after_submission` callback entirely. Without thoroughly examining the code however, I do not know if that will be possible.

Comment: thank you for the updated functions and the links to more info (the yoda conditions were interesting). However, I'm still seeing the payment gateway regardless of the selection made in the Gravity Form on the product. I trying `add_filter` since I have two functions that successfully hide the gateway which use this instead of `add_action` however, this didn't work either. 

You mentioned the after submission action. I'm wondering if I should look at gravity forms get input value instead: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_get_input_value/

Going to give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all the cart items and get the Gravity Field values. Then use your if logic to unset shipping methods

```
function disable_local_shipping_on_checkout($available_methods)
{

     // Find each product in the cart and add it to the $cart_ids array
     foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
         $cart_product = $values['_gravity_form_lead'];
         
         $field_value   = $cart_product[109]; //109 is the form field ID
         if ($field_value == 'Whatever field value you want') :

            unset($available_methods['wf_shipping_ups:03']); //You can find this by inspecting your shopping cart or checkout.
        endif;
    }
    return $available_methods;
}
```